# How to automatically enable/disable a phone line (dual SIM)?

Tags: iphone, automation, settings, sim, shortcuts-app

A common use case for having two lines on a single device (dual SIM) is that one of these lines is personal and the other for work.

As far as I can see, it is impossible to automatically toggle a data plan on or off on iOS 15 (I am referring to `Settings -> Mobile Data -> Data Plans -> Turn On This Line`).

I suspected that maybe Apple just has a different solution for that problem so I checked `Settings -> Focus -> Personal` to see if that allows me to turn off the work line. But I see no such option there.

I want to automatically turn off my work line after office hours, i.e. to not receive any calls or notifications on that line.

Is there a way to automatically turn off (perhaps using focus or shortcuts) a second line on an iOS device?

Comment: The last sentence did not ask for Apple's reasons but for any reasons at all why a developer would avoid (or be unable) to implement such a feature. I edited the question to further clarify this. I also edited the question title to highlight that the actual absence of the feature is not yet established.

Comment: I’m going to make a drastic edit, as there is a clear practical question here. The extra explanations and assumptions that shortcuts can’t do this today might be wrong. Lets leave that all for answers to sort out. A shortcuts expert might know precisely how to do this, a MDM expert might know a MDM command for this, focus could possibly be an avenue to a solution. Everyone is a beginner on iOS 16 and Apple can issue not features at any time for automation, so this might get a solve at any future date…

Comment: You are the expert here, so I'll let you do this, but my understanding of the community guidelines is that questions do not need to be purely practical but can also be "inspire answers that explain 'why' and 'how'" (https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). The background part of my question was intended to clarify that this is that kind of question.  I also believe that questions should  document whatever efforts the author has made to answer the question. This is why I would consider it appropriate to mention that Shortcuts does not provide an action to toggle said setting.